# Ext net set default panel in tabpanel

Tags: extjs

I have this code:

```
<ext:TabPanel ID="*" runat="server">
      <Items>
        <ext:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server" Title="*" Closable="false">
          <Loader ID="*" runat="server" Url="*.aspx" Mode="Frame">
            <LoadMask ShowMask="True" />
          </Loader>
        </ext:Panel>
          <ext:Panel ID="panel2" runat="server" Title="*" Closable="false">
          <Loader ID="*" runat="server" Url="*.aspx" Mode="Frame">
            <LoadMask ShowMask="True" />
          </Loader>
        </ext:Panel>
        <ext:Panel ID="panel3" runat="server" Title="*" Closable="false" Hidden="true">
          <Loader ID="Loader" runat="server" Url="*.aspx" Mode="Frame">
            <LoadMask ShowMask="True" />
          </Loader>
        </ext:Panel>
      </Items>
    </ext:TabPanel>
```

I need to set the first panel as default panel ( the panel that is shown when the page is loaded )

Comment: you can use `defaults` config in `tappanel` like [this](http://examples.ext.net/#/search/tabbarheaderposition)

Comment: How can I specify the default tab using defaults?

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this:

```
<ext:TabPanel ID="*" ActiveIndex="0" runat="server">
```